# If I switch to custom user model, will I have to migrate all my existing User accounts?

Tags: python, django, authentication, web-applications

Since django 1.5 it is possible to have a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user). I already have a lot of users in my database.. if I upgrade to my own (custom) user model, will I have to manually migrate all the already existing users to the new model - or will this work automatically?

In other words, let's say I have an account for `joe` in my app. After adding the custom user model, will `joe` be able to log in, or I have to manually create a new account for him?

Comment: Docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) specifically say that if you are trying to implement a custom user in an existing app, you'll have to do a data migration.  There's a decent chance that you could get what you need with just a User subclass (or any other one-to-one class associated to User) though, which would probably be a much easier migration.

Comment: Ah, I suppose I should have RTFD :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need to migrate the model if you provide your own User class.

Instructions can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904046/migrating-existing-auth-user-data-to-new-django-1-5-custom-user-model/15059338#15059338).