# migrate user and userprofile to new user in django 1.5

Tags: django, model, migration

I tried to follow instructions in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904046/migrating-existing-auth-user-data-to-new-django-1-5-custom-user-model) but didn't work. I bet due to the following:

1. We have an existing User class is models.py which is a **proxy**:

   ```
   class User(auth_models.User):
   """
       Wrapper to make methods on user_profile one call
   """
   objects = UserManager()
   def title(self):
       # TODO This probably makes too many SQL queries by default?
       return self.get_profile().title

   class Meta:
       proxy = True
   ```
2. The UserProfile model has a 1-to-1 with the built-in User table:

   ```
   import django.contrib.auth.models as auth_models 

   class UserProfile(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(auth_models.User) ...
   ```
3. But other model use the proxy class:

   ```
   class Job(models.Model):
       ...
       user = models.ForeignKey(User)
       ...
   ```

As you can imagine, some parts of the code refer to the proxy class.

Can someone suggest a variation on the above answer in this scenario? Can I just remove the Meta/proxy attribute and be happy? What will happen to the UserProfile relationship? I dont want to lost that in the process of updating, in oder to recover that data and put it in the new User model (as the new Django 1.5 allows)

**UPDATE 1**

I made some progress, I think. I also read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/VwLF8G3IBC4) and did the following:

1. I changed the reference to the proxy in Job for auth_models.User. The app continues to work: proxies are transparent to foreign keys, good.
2. I then removed the proxy meta in our User, and generated the migration as in answer to question mentioned. Now I am getting this error report:

   ```
   CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
   auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field     'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
   auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
   tao.user: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
   tao.user: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
   ```

So, it seems to me that the related built-in tables for groups and permissions are having issues. Any ideas?