# Migrate existing user to django 1.5 custom user (AbstractBaseUser)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south, django-1.5

I'm working on an existing Django project in Django 1.4. I want to upgrade to Django 1.5 for implementing a custom user model. I have to ensure that my existing information is not deleted from the database(Postgres 9.1).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904046/migrating-existing-auth-user-data-to-new-django-1-5-custom-user-model) explains the steps to be done for data migration using South but only for `AbstractUser`. I have to use `AbstractBaseUser`. Is there any way?

My existing model is like :

```
class Individual(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self', unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
  ....(some many to many and foreign key)
```

I want to change it to something like this.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, Individual, PermissionsMixin):
  email = models.EmailFeild(max_length=50, unique=True)
  is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  username = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
  USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

The individual class will contain all previous fields except the user. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[Document how to migrate from a built-in User model to a custom User model](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313) thread has some workaround discussions.