# Django1.5 not overwriting auth_users

Tags: python, database, django, django-1.5

I would like a  bigger `auth_user` table, including 2-3 extra fields.

The thing is that the code below is creating a new one, exactly the same as the auth_user one with the extra fields but it is not replacing it.

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "myaccount.MyUser"
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

    class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    gender = models.DateField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birthday = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Instead of creating a new table called `myaccount_MyUser`. How can I **replace the current `auth_user` table** instead of creating a new table?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this one can help you :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user

Comment: It is great that you are trying to help the asker out. However, leaving an answer with only a link can be harmful in some cases. While your answer is good now, if the link were ever to die, your answer would lose it's value. So it will be helpful if you summarize the content from the article in your answer. See [this](http://goo.gl/wQTjc) question for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

One hackish way that I didn't try and don't recommend would be to specify the table name in the model with:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    class Meta:
        db_table = auth_user
```

What I recommend is going along with the new table and migrating the data from the old one using south datamigration. Here is a detailed answer on how to do that:

[Migrating existing auth.User data to new Django 1.5 custom user model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904046/migrating-existing-auth-user-data-to-new-django-1-5-custom-user-model)

Comment: It's better creating from 0 than to migrate it (when it's not needed).

Answer (score -1):

I think that you have to

```
import first django.contrib.auth.models 
import AbstractUser
```

in your models.py before to get a way to extend with `AbstractUser`. it should work with that

Comment: I've got it already imported even though I have not written it here. Otherwise it'd have shown me an error.

Comment: ok , try to import also AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin because AbstractUser extend both of this. so you can figure out what happen exactly.

Comment: Imported both, same result.

Comment: check your settings file about MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',) INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',)

Comment: ok, let me try something and get back to you if i find solution.